# Log a java class using log4j called from a Coldfusion application

Tags: java, coldfusion, log4j

I want to be able to log debugging messages from my Java classes in a file on my web server, using log4j.  I am able to log messages successfully to a file on the server if the Java classes are run from a JUnit test, using the following settings:

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=D:/logs/fair.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, rollingFile
```

FairScheduler.java:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FairScheduler.class);
logger.info("initializing Scheduler");
```

But when I deploy the application to my Coldfusion application, the log messages are no longer logged.

How can I configure my Coldfusion server to log messages to this log file (or view any of my log4j log messages at all)?

Comment: Did you check the -out logs?  It may be writing to there.

Comment: yeah, none of the /runtime/out/coldfusion-out logs contain any of my log4j messages

Comment: Are you sure Coldfusion's service account has permission to create/modify the log file?

Comment: I'd try a google search for "coldfusion log4j" - there seems to be a bit of info out there that can help you.

Comment: There's some good general info out there, but all of these articles deal with configuring log4j within a coldfusion component.  I'm calling a java class from a coldfusion component and logging within the Java class, which is a bit different.

Comment: @Kyle - A lot of it may still apply. What configuration file are you attempting to use within CF? Also, have you enabled debugging to see more details? I believe the jvm argument is `-Dlog4j.debug=true`

Comment: man, i had a problem like this a few years ago.  We needed log4j for an API to another app.  i don't know if this is the same issue, but we found that certain version of the log4j would not work with coldfusion.  I think we solved it by going to an older version....i think.  It been a long time.

Comment: @Limey - I have had a few problems with log4j. But the basic version that ships with CF is usually okay for most stuff. Were you trying to load a newer *(separate)* version maybe? My take was @Kyle was trying to use the built in version. Could be wrong though..

Comment: yeah, we were using a different version that came with the API.

Comment: @Limey - Yeah, that can be a ... "challenge" ;)